# Can you rename functions in Visual Studio Code for C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Does Visual Studio Code (VSC) have a genuine renaming feature for C++? I know I can replace strings, but this causes errors when I try to rename a function whose name is an infix of another function.

This feature does exist for other languages in VSC and Visual Studio 2017 (which I used before) does come with it, too. I moved from Visual Studio to VSC for my little project because I need a terminal window and I prefer having it within the mainwindow of my IDE.

I'm using VSC 1.12.2

Comment: Yes, I don't remember how you find the vanilla feature, probably if you right click a code symbol it will give you the option to refactor( and I think it lets you choose what to change in case it makes any mistakes ).

Comment: The context menu only gives you the option to 'change all occurences', which manipulates the target string. No such thing as 'refactor' for C++ it seems, but I've seen it in other languages.

Comment: Huh, on googling, looks like VS is missing the feature for C++. There is a free addon "Visual C++ Refactoring" on the visual studio marketplace. I can recommend Visual assist but it has a far broader range of features and is probably a little pricey if you just get it just for the refactor tool.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the devs don't really care about vscode being used for c/cpp development. The original issue was raised over two and a half years ago and yet here we are despite thousands of upvotes.
They didn't even care to prioritise it so I just switched to CLion and not looking back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally renaming [was implemented](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/296#issuecomment-537314529) in C/C++ extention the version 0.26.0-insiders

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot. However, as of writing this it is the [second most upvoted feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/296) in the vscode-cpptools plugin. The *most* upvoted feature request happens to be an improved [find all references](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/15) feature which works across translation units. Since 'find all references' is a prerequisite for renaming/refactoring we will hopefully see something soon.

Answer (score 1):

With the [C/C++ extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) installed, place the cursor on the symbol (e.g. function name) to be refactored, then press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. Alternatively right-click and select [Rename Symbol](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring) from the context-menu.

A line editor will pop up below the symbol. Make the desired changes then press enter. VS Code should update all detected symbol occurrences.